# Changing the response in ActionFilter in ASP.Net Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using both normal data annotation validations and my custom validations in my ASP.Net Core Web Api project. Framework itself adds validation errors to ModelState and according to the business logic, I also add my custom validations using `ModelState.AddModelError()`. What I want to do is, just before sending the response to the client, I want to check if `ModelState.IsValid` and if it is not valid, I want to clear the response and send an error JSON in a format I want.

I can do this easily in the controller itself but if I check the `ModelState` in every controller action, there will be lots of duplicate code. So I wanted to do it in a ActionFilter.

Here is the method I want to use:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Change the response
    }
}
```

I did everything I needed for the first part so I can debug the code until it gets to this method. I also have access to `ModelState` so I only need to modify the response and send a JSON response. This sounded easy when I thought about it but even after trying more than 10 different codes for changing the response, I haven't been able to do it.

I thought simple code like this would work, but it doesn't (this isn't JSON of course, I tried it with simple text, this doesn't work either):

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));
```

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is this a good idea? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?
2. If this is a good idea, how can I modify the response in ActionFilter?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this _after_ executing the action? If the model isn't valid, wouldn't you want to avoid calling the action in the first place?

Comment: Action filters are intended to interact with the results through the `Result` property on the context. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#action-filters

Comment: @StriplingWarrior If model isn't valid, it is not saved to the database so there are no problems about doing it after executing the action, at least that's what I thought. Is that a bad idea? Also, using the `Result` property fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's probably a bad idea. If you have an invalid model and your action fails to check for that before doing something expensive or state-changing, you'd give the impression that the request was rejected while actually allowing it to make a change. The controller is a fine place to handle custom model validation, but if you're trying to move model state logic up to the level of an action filter then you should also move the validation to something that gets executed before the action is executed, like a ValidationAttribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do model validation before the action is executed, otherwise it will always execute the code in the action no matter the validation fails or not.

If you must do it after action executed:

```
public class ModelStateValidationFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)

    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get all model state errors
            var errors = context.ModelState
                .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .SelectMany(e => e.Value.Errors)
                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
                .ToList();

            // Create a custom error response
            var errorResponse = new
            {
                Message = "Validation failed",
                Errors = errors
            };

            // Replace the response with the custom error response
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(errorResponse);
        }
            
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //if you agree do model validation operation before the action is executed, just move the code here
    }
}
```

If your project is Web Api and the controllers are declared with `[ApiController]` attribute, be sure set `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` **true** to disable automatic model validation in `Program.cs` file(No matter you do model validation operation before or after the action executed in action filter, you always need set this property to true. Otherwise it will not execute the action filter and fail with bad request by default model validation because default model validation middleware occurs before action filter):

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{

    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ModelStateValidationFilter)); // Add the filter globally
}).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; // Disable automatic model validation
});
```

Comment: Both StriplingWarrior's and your response fixed the issue. Reason I am using `OnActionExecuted` because I add custom validation in a service (similar to a controller). So I only have access to that validation error after action is executed. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you do validation after the action executed, all the operation in the action will be hit, does this influence your result? If not, you can do the validation in `OnActionExecuted `.